Nissan V6 petrol idle speed
I have modified my Nissan (Terrano / Pathfinder) which has the vg30 petrol engine. I have discarded the AC pump (which was stuffed) and replaced it with an alternator. ,I have also fitted two electric winches, two batteries and of course now the two alternators. When I activate the winch dash switch which activates two solenoids for the winches ( this parallels the two systems for extra current) I would really like to raise the engine idle speed to say 1200~1800 RPM so as to gain the extra 100amps or so from the alternators.
A: can someone simply explain how the "old" AC idle control valve (is?) worked or does the ECM do something else as well.
B; I thought about fitting an electric/ air solenoid connecting a "before/after" throttle butterfly bypass to allow extra air passed the butterfly, but I suspect the MAF would upset my thinking.
Thoughts anyone?

What year is your Terrano/Pathfinder? Engine size? Is this EFI with a drive by wire throttle using a servo motor to open/close throttle, plain throttle body with an idle air control valve, or very old school carburetor w/linkages and solenoid for idle speed management when using ac? Perhaps Nissan Terrano/Pathfinder forums may help with like minded owners. BTW, mass air flow (MAF) sensors measure air flow regardless of throttle plate position. Its placed before the throttle; the ecm determines (from maf, map, tps, coolant  and upstream O2 sensor to determine air/fuel mixtures, cold/warm idle.

Hi, it is a 1994 Nissan Terrano V6  R3m Engine type vg30 3 litre. the throttle is a mechanical butterfly operated with a bowden cable, but has what I perceive to be a throttle position sensor.  hope that clarifies.

Your cable operated throttle body uses the idle air control valve with a fixed throttle opening (never fully closed) to bypass the fixed throttle plate for supplemental air for; cold engine startup (high idle), ac operation (bumping idle up to compensate for compressor load) and varying electrical loads (night time lighting, ac, your custom 2-alternator/2 battery/winch loads. The ecm controls iacv opening/closing to maintain idle speed and one more additional use; during deceleration with gas pedal released (coasting) from speeds above approximately 12-18 mph, the ecm opens the iacv to keep the rpms above idle (around 1200 rpm), emissions requirement, while coasting until speed drops below 12-15 mph when the ecm commands the iacv to close, returning to idle speed. The iacv is never fully closed.
A simple work around for your unique setup might be an additional throttle cable into the car interior with an adjustable friction lock to hold the cable in any position that corresponds to your desired idle rpm needs. Older choke cables were used decades ago. Small single engine aircraft use a throttle cable and adjustable friction lock for the pilot to adjust engine rpm.
